# STM32-H407 write program with USB mini cable (USB-OTG)

Tags: stm32, usb-otg

I have Olimex STM32-H407.  Manual says you require JTAG/SWD cable.  Until I get JTAG/SWD cable, I am trying to write program on the board with USB mini cable.  Is it possible?  My PC or IDE (crossworks) do not seem to recognize STM32-H407 when USB cable is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for first time no! You should use the J-TAG for write the program. if you want download the program to MCU by USB, you should change the bootloader that suport USB. but if i were you, i use the J-TAG for this because the many IDE suport it(J-TAG) and as well as it has many advantages, for example you can debug your program.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the free version of Keil to program it as it supports my STM32F4 from the usb connection..(have to install the drivers for the STLink though)

If not as the other poster said above get a JTAG/SWD cable..

If you want something high end then one of the Segger series as it's supported by practically any IDE but they can get ridiculously expensive..~(£1000's)

I personally have the Segger Jlink Edu version (£50) and works well as long as your product isn't commerical and it's supported well in Keil and most other ARM IDEs.

A really cheap way to program ARM chips though is to buy an STM32F4-discovery board as they are only £9 and contain the STLINK programmer on the board and a pin header for it..So you could use it just as a programmer for other boards..

Pretty cool huh..

Comment: I could not ask this question before purchasing and doing some try.  I wish I bought discovery board.  Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 3 main approaches for ARM Microcontroller development.

The first is to use the FOSS (Free Open Source Software) tools, a good starting point is launchpad: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded. You need a JTAG cable which supports OpenOCD, for example, the relatively cheap Olimex one here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8278.

The second is to use the KEIL toolset, which uses their proprietary (but official) compiler and IDE with the ULINK 2/ME/Pro adapters. A free version is available (code size limited), and bootleg (but functional) ULINK2 adapters are readily available off of eBay for ~$20. This approach lets you use the most "official" tools, since KEIL is a subsidiary of ARM, and you have access to the most advanced trace/debugging features. This also is the most vendor independent option, since KEIL Uvision supports hardware from many manufacturers.

The third is to use vendor specific approach by using a vendor's IDE and compiler, for example, STLink as lilSebastian mentioned. I know NXP has something similar through their LPC-XPresso. These usually have their own IDE which is coupled to the vendor specific debugger hardware, and is usually the cheapest option - but of course you are locked into that vendor.

Comment: Thanks for listing what approaches there are.  I will stick with 2nd approach until I get used to STM32.